# PHP - SoapClient and typemap to prevent element dissapearing

Tags: php, xml, parsing, soap

I am trying to see what is going on when SoapClient is parsing Soap response. When I call `$client->__getLastResponse()` I get this:

```
<ns0:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <ns0:Body>
    <ns1:ListPositionBranchResponse xmlns:ns1="http://atollon.com/enterprise/wsdl">
      <result>OK</result>
      <time>0.00505090</time>
      <ROWS>
        <ROW>
          <idPos>1409000</idPos>
          <idBranch>122482000</idBranch>
          <positionName>ekonom</positionName>
        </ROW>
        <ROW>
          <idPos>1412000</idPos>
          <idBranch>122488000</idBranch>
          <positionName>IT specialista</positionName>
        </ROW>
      </ROWS>
    </ns1:ListPositionBranchResponse>
  </ns0:Body>
</ns0:Envelope>
```

I create SoapClient this way:

```
    $client = new SoapClient("https://mblue.atollon.com/recruitment.wsdl", array('trace' => 1, 'exceptions'=>true, 'location' => "https://mblue.atollon.com/soap"));
$requestParams = array(
      'server' => "SERVER",
      'session' => "SESSION"
  );
  $response = $client->ListPositionBranch($requestParams);
```

but when I do var_dump of response, there is no idPos element. I have tried it on 64bit Linux machine, but it doesn't work also, so it's not INT limitation. So I wanted to see what is going on, and tried this:

```
  $client = new SoapClient("https://mblue.atollon.com/recruitment.wsdl", array('trace' => 1, 'exceptions'=>true, 'location' => "https://mblue.atollon.com/soap", 'typemap' => array(
          array(
            'type_ns' => 'http://atollon.com/enterprise/wsdl',
            'type_name' => 'idPos',
            'to_xml' => 'to_long_xml',
            'from_xml' => 'from_long_xml',
          )
      )));
```

And the functions themselves:

```
  function to_long_xml($longVal) {
    return '<long>' . $longVal . '</long>';
  }
  function from_long_xml($xmlFragmentString) {
    return (string)strip_tags($xmlFragmentString);
  }
```

But the `from_long_xml` function is not even fired.. I tried to change `type_name` to I guess all elements in that response, but it never fires it. I am out of ideas - what can be wrong - I am guessing it might be the namespace, but I have tried both listed in xml with no luck. How to get that `typemap` (or the `idPos`) working?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`type_name` in `typemap` element should be name of type defined in WSDL of service. I had weird experience, that `typemap` should be defined before `classmap` element.